# Command line FTP remote backup

Tags: backup, ftp

I have a ftp upload script correctly working on a desktop machine. After moving everything on a Windows Server 2008 R2 it does not work.

Should I change the Firewall settings to be able to do the upload?
What about the scheduled task user privileges instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Way too many variables to provide an answer without some more details.

Comment: Very simple script, like this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the ftp process without using the script, i.e. from the command line. I think that should be the first troubleshooting step.

If it works from command line, does script work without scheduler? and so on.

Comment: I am starting to think I need to open a port to be able to do this...

Comment: Depending on active or passive ftp on server side, you might need to open either ports 20-21 or 21 and other ports. Here is a good guide: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html